# How to dynamically remove a LinearLayout by clicking unclicking a radio button?

Tags: android, radio-button, android-linearlayout

This is my code to add a new linear layout:

```
public void onClick_addContact(View v)
    {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutLinear);
            layout.addView(linearlayout(_intMyLineCount));
            _intMyLineCount++;



    }


    private EditText editText(int _intID) {
            EditText editText = new EditText(this);
            editText.setId(_intID);
            editText.setHint("My lines");
            editText.setWidth(180);         

            editTextList.add(editText);
            return editText;
        }

       private TextView textView(int _intID)
        {
            TextView txtviewAll=new TextView(this);
            txtviewAll.setId(_intID);
            txtviewAll.setText("My lines:");        

            textviewList.add(txtviewAll);
            return txtviewAll;
        }

       private RadioButton button(int _intID)
       {
           RadioButton btn = new RadioButton(this);
           btn.setId(_intID);
           btn.setOnClickListener(newContact);


           return btn;


       }

       OnClickListener newContact = new OnClickListener() {
                //onClick view
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutLinear);

                    layout.addView(linearlayout(_intMyLineCount));

                        _intMyLineCount++;


                }
               };

       private LinearLayout linearlayout(int _intID)
        {
            LinearLayout LLMain=new LinearLayout(this);
            LLMain.setId(_intID);       
            LLMain.addView(textView(_intID));
            LLMain.addView(editText(_intID));
            LLMain.addView(button(_intID));
            LLMain.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            linearlayoutList.add(LLMain);
            return LLMain;

        } 
}
```

As of now, if any radio button is clicked then a new linear layout gets added. How do I change this, if any radio button is clicked, then the corresponding linear layout gets removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [setVisibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) method. If you know the ID of the layout, you can do do a `findViewById` and then use `myLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutLinear);
layout.removeView(findViewById(removeId));
```

Should be helpful..

Answer (score 0):

You set a tag at the new LinearLayout for exmeple "the layout corresponding to the first radio button" and you can retrieve this layout for delete it with findViewByTag.